# While using Openlayers, unable to display WebGLPointsLayer

Tags: node.js, apache, webgl, openlayers

I am using current version of OpenLayers (8.2).

Using a local Nodejs server, I am able to successfully display thousands of points using a  WebGLPointsLayer.

However, when I upload the dist files to my shared server running Apache the points do not display.  The map is working since it displays the baselayer (i.e. OSM).

From what I have read, Apache server (in my case 2.4) is not normally setup to display WebGL graphics unless additional libraries are loaded (which I cannot do because I have shared hosting).

Is this correct?  or is there another possible reason why the WebGLPoints are displayed using Nodejs vs. Apache?

Any suggestions on what (open source) production servers should be able to serve WebGL graphics right "out of the box"?

Comment: its not the case with apache, also when you run your website on client machine it looks for webgl support on client machine. can you show your hosted code ? also  any error you encounter there while running hosted version?